# Postgresql copying data into a table

Tags: postgresql

I am using the copy command in Postgresql and I have a line of data in a text file that is tab seperated and I would like to copy it into the db table.

I get an error saying:
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY real_acct1, line 113038

So I went to the line 113038 from the text file and copied it along with 4 or 5 neighboring lines into a new text file and behold that new data went in.

Any helpful thoughts?  This is parcel data attributes info.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file? What PostgreSQL version?

Comment: @underdark Thanks.  I have already encountered encoding issues and I've preprocessed the text file with python to get those encodings handled.  But this seems different than the link you pointed out because if I get the one line that is throwing the error and put it in another text file then postgressql loads fine.

Comment: @filiprem I am not sure.  See my comment to underdark.  I was having problems with the spanish n-accented and also some weird << characters.  I moved them into another text file and will load them manually.  But this issue seems to be different.  Thanks.

Comment: Since this question is not directly GIS-related, I think you'll find a better audience directly on stackoverflow. I'll migrate your question there.

Comment: @underdark Thanks. I removed that one line and loaded 1.3 million records successfully. Then I loaded that one line (record) from a text file with only it. I guess that it had to do with the number of records as when you see my above statement on how it works with a smaller number of lines.  Maybe someone else can shed more light

Comment: The error message says that there is a NUL byte at this line. If you copied it into another file and saved, there is a real chance that the editor filtered out the NUL byte. A lot of text editors would do that (Windows Notepad for example).

Comment: The original data was in a text file.  I guess you're suggesting the paste into the new notepad file did it.  I want to be able to write a script to catch whatever is throwing off the copy operation.  How could I get that NULL value into a text file for testing so I don't have to scan the whole 1.3 millions lines just for testing.

Comment: I would say `grep -a -n -P '\x{0}' filename` with GNU grep. It should output the offending line's number followed by the line contents. Remove the -n option to get just the line contents.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is actually one of character encoding.

The easiest way to deal with this is running your import data through iconv (assuming you're on a unix machine).

iconv -f original_charset -t utf-8 originalfile > newfile